# Is setting up fstab like this dangerous?

Tags: linux, fstab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is noload option do in fstab?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61306/what-is-noload-option-do-in-fstab)

```
UUID=fb2b6c2e-a8d7-4855-b109-c9717264da8a /                       ext4    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        1 1
UUID=71362665-f627-41e1-a093-de42a0a356e2 /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=8024a5cd-af4b-4776-af0d-65ad80af8649 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
/dev/sdd1               /home4                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1               /home3                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1               /home2                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
```

And now server fails to reboot. It can reboot but reject all kind of connections.

This is what my provider said:

```
Yeah, the noload option might be problematic... I can't edit /etc/fstab from
single user mode, but I might be able to edit it using one of my pxe boot tools
to enter the filesystem manually. With regards to your request about
/var/log/messages and /var/log/secure, I'm afraid I can't do that for you
(technically, I'm already bordering on managed services by editing your fstab
for you, but I am justifying it as necessary to restore connectivity)...
```

> I'm unable to paste the actual error messages without manually typing
>   them out, but I assure you they're not really very descriptive
>   (basically, system indicates that it is unable to remount root in
>   read/write mode, and then errors composed of read/write problems,
>   particularly in /var are printed to the screen)...

I have no idea putting noload or noatime at / can cause so much problem. Actually what was the problem? Can anyone explain?